# Container on the IoT Edge module network can not connect to upstream AMPQ port

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I am trying to setup my personal linux machine (which is inside virtualbox vm) as edge runtime device.
And i have followed everystep mentioned in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge?view=iotedge-2020-11

While running

```
iotedge check
```

I am facing the error below -
[image]

Let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-starting VM and running

```
iotedge config apply
```

did the trick.